# Does a screenplay include dialogues between the characters?

Tags: fiction, screenwriting

Someone asked me to write screenplay and not the script, hence I want to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, dialogue is included in a screenplay.

The word "screenplay" is movie-speak for "script", and it's exactly the equivalent of a play's script. (The TV version of "script" is "teleplay".)

In addition to dialogue, A screenplay includes actions and descriptions. Sometimes it's appropriate to include scene transitions and [camera directions](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/28463/26).

There are a few specific, accepted ways to [format a screenplay](https://www.wgfoundation.org/screenwriting-library/faq-writing-resources-2/#4). Writing software like Final Draft and Scrivener will include screenplay templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get really technical, a script is any written work with a story, dialogue, and a setting. A screenplay is a type of script, so it would include the story, dialogue, and setting, like this example: https://www.writersstore.com/how-to-write-a-screenplay-a-guide-to-scriptwriting/

Answer (score -3):

write a screenplay. If it's in English. Script and screenplay are the same thing.*emphasized text*

Comment: I'm sorry but this is wrong. All screenplays are scripts, but all scripts are not screenplays.